# how to sort articles in the designated category of WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

There are many categories in my wordpress ,and there are many articles in every category.
Now i want to sort articles in the 'python' category at my willing .
How can i do then?

[image]

Comment: where do you want it sorted ?

Comment: in my category named 'python'.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to add a meta box to save a metakey for each post as i can't see a logic for the sort order you want, something like a orderby num e.g. 'pythonsort' see - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

then you can add this to your functions file:

```
function sort_by_order(){
   if ( is_admin() ) {
      $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
      $wp_query->set( 'meta_key', 'pythonsort' );
   }
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'sort_by_order' );
```